# AWS Region issue while deploying cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have created a CloudFormation template where I am deploying a Lambda function which will take code from S3 bucket from a zipped file. The bucket is in us-west-2 region.

My issue here is that the template deployment is failing to create Lambda function if the user deploys it in another region apart from us-west-2 in another account since it's not able to find the bucket in the above mentioned region.

Also, i cannot directly add the code in the template since the code has some dependency files.

Sharing the snippet of the code. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thanks

```
Resources:
  DMARCFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: lambda-code-bucket
        S3Key: Lambda.zip
      Runtime: python3.8
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Timeout: 15
      TracingConfig:
        Mode: Active
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not CloudFormation issue. That's how lambda works. the ZIP and the function **must be in same region**. You have to replicate your ZIP to all regions and accounts were you want to create your function.

Comment: Thanks for you response @Marcin. Do you think is there a way to replicate the code in all the regions because if I create s\S3 buckets in different region it has to be of different names but I have mentioned  only 1 bucket in my code. Is there a possible workaround. Thanks

Comment: @ASingh One would be through a custom resource as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/deploying-aws-lambda-functions-using-aws-cloudformation-the-portable-way/). Or naming your buckets using `'lambda-zips-${AWS::Region}'` pattern.

Comment: @ASingh How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: @ASingh No problem. Glad it worked out:-)